# subtract the first and last element of a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got following list:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[(0, 0)], [(6, 0)], [(7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0)], [(10, 0)]]
```

And what I want is the following:

```
>>> substract(list_of_lists)
[6, 1, 1]
```

Basically I have a list of lists. Each of those lists is a list of tuples. I want to to subtract the first element of the last tuple in a list from the first element of the first tuple in the subsequent list. For a more pictographic explanation,

[[(*0*, 0)], [(*6*, 0)], [(*7*, 0), (8, 0), (**9**, 0)], [(**10**, 0)]]

*6* - *0* = *6*

*7* - *6* = 1

**10** - **9** = 1

Comment: "What i want is that the first element of a tuple in a list in list_of_lists substract with the previous list with the first element in the last tuple. So in substract(list) happens following:6-0=6,7-6=1,10-9=1 and give the results in a list." This is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ll[i][0][0] - ll[i-1][-1][0] for i in xrange(1,len(ll))]
```

Comment: For i==1, second and first elements of the list must be searched by their indexes. For i==2, third and second elements must be searched by their indexes, that is to say the second element must be searched for the 2nd time. And so on, hence each element must be searched two times. - However, I tested, and your solution is faster than mine, certainly because it takes less time to find an element thanks to its index than doing assignements as in my code - So I upvote

Answer (score 0):

So you can access the values in this list of lists using indexes.  From that point you can now access say the first instance of the number six by calling,

```
list_of_list[1][0][0]
```

where the first index refers to the list within the list, the second refers to the tuple within the list and the last one refers to the element in the tuple.  Another example might be to access the 8,

```
list_of_list[2][1][0]
```

From there you should be able to create a loop on your own that cycles through the list and outputs the desired array.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
In [9]: ll = [[(0, 0)], [(6, 0)], [(7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0)], [(10, 0)]]

In [10]: first = [l[0][0] for l in ll]

In [11]: last = [l[-1][0] for l in ll]

In [12]: [f - l for (f, l) in zip(first[1:], last[:-1])]
Out[12]: [6, 1, 1]
```

Comment: You create an object **first**, you create another object **last**, you create a third object **first[1:]**, you create a 4th object **last[:-1]**, and another one more object **zip(first[1:], last[:-1])]**. So much work ! I tested: your solution is 25% longer than mine which is 20 % longer that the solution of Squazic

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [[(0, 0)],
      [(6, 0)],
      [(7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0)],
      [(10, 0)]]
for x in li:
    print x
print

def iti(li):
    a = li[0]
    for b in li[1:]:
        yield b[0][0]-a[-1][0]
        a = b

print list(iti(li))
```

In this solution, the list is iterated only one time (with b), that is to say each element is assigned only one time

Edit: no, in fact each element (that is to say object in the list) is assigned a first time to **b**, and then another time to **a**